# Is it possible to define countability of a set using a function mapping $\mathbb Q$ to some set $S$?

Tags: general-topology

A set $S$ is countable if you can find a function $f:\mathbb N \mapsto S$ which is surjective. But we know that $card(\mathbb N) = card(\mathbb Q)$, as $\mathbb Q$ is countable.(Or is this assumption wrong?) So is it legal to say a set $S$ is countable if we can find a surjective function $f:\mathbb Q \mapsto S$  ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Note that since $Q$ is countable, you already have a surjective function $$g:N\to Q.$$

So if you have a  surjective function $$f:Q\to S$$ then you have the surjective composite function $$fog:N\to S$$. Thus S is countable.